# How to Navigate to a screen not displayed in BottomTabNavigator or DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Use Case:
From a FlatList, click an item go to a Details Page.

Long Winded Explanation:
I have a screen I don't want to appear in my Tab or Drawer menus (No need to have an Item on my navigation bars), but unless I add Item to my Drawer or Tab Navigators, I can't navigate to the Item page.

If I do add them to the Tab or Drawer Navigator(s) then that path works.

### from Items.js

```
export default class Items extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: false,
    data: json_data.features,
    error: null,
  }

Navigate_To_Item = (item) => {
  // This works without Navigator present
  console.log(item)
  // This only works if I have Item in my Drawer or Tab Nav
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Item', {item});
}

render() {
  return (
   <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
     <Text style={styles.headline}>List of Items</Text>
       <FlatList
         data={this.state.data}
         renderItem={({ item }) =>
           <TouchableWithoutFeedback
             onPress={() => this.Navigate_To_Item(item)} >
               <View style={styles.listContainer}>
                 <Text style={styles.item}>{item.properties.name</Text>
                 <Text style={styles.land}>{item.properties.descrption}</Text>
               </View>
             </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
           }
         />
   </SafeAreaView>
   )
  }
}
```

I can share my Drawer and Tab Navigators but again, they work fine, if I add Item, but I don't want Item to show up in my Menus.

Spent a few hours on this and I'm stumped. Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your

```
Navigate_To_Item = (item) => {
  // This works without Navigator present
  console.log(item)
  // This only works if I have Item in my Drawer or Tab Nav
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Item', {item});
}
```

Which route does navigation point to? You could have a Stacknavigator which has 2 screens - your tab/drawer navigator and your Itemscreen. You can send navigator with screenProps so you can still access the Stacknavigator inside Tab/Drawer navigator.

check the answer in [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288199/tabsnavigator-inside-stacknavigator), and you might understand what I mean.

Comment: You're answer is a little vague, but I'll give it to you... ;-)

Main Points
1) You can't just jump around to screens
2) In order to speciffy where you can jump around, you need to list those options in a Navigator.

If you want to have a Tab Navigator with `Add Item` and `List Items` and then when you're on `ListScreen` You want to have an `ItemScreen` that you can reach when you click an Item on the List, you have to have an additional Stack Navigator on your `ListScreen`.

As explained here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html#a-stack-navigator-for-each-tab